# Pandas, подменить в столбце значения int на списки (One-Hot-Encoding)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с pd.DataFrame.loc

Есть таблица df:
максимальный размер типа(например) - 5

```
    types
24433   3
23933   1
23433   5
22933   3
22433   0
```

Хочу что бы стало так:

```
                types
24433   [0,0,0,1,0,0]
23933   [0,1,0,0,0,0]
23433   [0,0,0,0,0,1]
22933   [0,0,0,1,0,0]
22433   [1,0,0,0,0,0]
```

использую для этого:

```
 #df_types.index - это таблица типов и количество на каждый тип
 #_____________
 # (index)types   count
 #       1         42
 #       5         50

 for type_number, i in enumerate(df_types.index):
        #создаю нулевую матрицу в размер количества типов
        type_vector = np.zeros(6)
        #на место типа ставлю 1
        type_vector[type_number] = 1 
        df.loc[df.types == type_number, 'types'] = type_vector
```

Error:

> ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an
>   iterable

Я конечно понимаю что я могу пройтись по всему списку целиком и создать новый список `[[0,0,0,1,0,0],..]` и потом его приклеить, но это же не самый оптимальный способ.

Comment: Вы уверены, что хотите получить результат в одном столбце вместо множества столбцов (по одному для каждого уникального типа) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно [`One-Hot-Encoding`](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-one-hot-encode-sequence-data-in-python/) делается так, чтобы получить 2D матрицу, где каждый столбец это уникальное значение:

```
In [263]: df.types.astype(str).str.get_dummies()
Out[263]:
       0  1  3  5
24433  0  0  1  0
23933  0  1  0  0
23433  0  0  0  1
22933  0  0  1  0
22433  1  0  0  0
```

можно сделать и так как у вас в вопросе (хранить списки в ячейках), но в этом случае вы не сможете применять большинство встроенных векторизированных методов и функций, т.к. практически все они ожидают скалярные значения в ячейках DataFrame'а:

```
In [277]: df['new'] = df.types.astype(str).str.get_dummies().values.tolist()

In [278]: df
Out[278]:
       types           new
24433      3  [0, 0, 1, 0]
23933      1  [0, 1, 0, 0]
23433      5  [0, 0, 0, 1]
22933      3  [0, 0, 1, 0]
22433      0  [1, 0, 0, 0]
```

> Как это работает?

Один из самых распространенных способов добавления нового столбца - это:

```
df['col_name'] = list_or_array_alike
```

где `list_or_array_alike` это pd.Series, np.array, список, или нечто подобное списку, в котором чисентов совпадает с числом строк в DataFrame. Поэтому преобразовав 2D numpy.array (размерности: число строк в DF x число уникальных значений) в список списков Pandas позволяет вставить эту структуру в столбец. Т.к. число элементов внешнего списка совпадает с числом строк DF, внутренние списки будут присвоены построчно новому столбцу.

---

Чтобы явно указать словарь значений (в том случае если не все необходимые значения присутствуют в выборке) можно воспользоваться [sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html):

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vect = CountVectorizer(token_pattern=r'(?u)\b\w+\b', vocabulary=list('012345'))

r = vect.fit_transform(df['types'].astype(str))
```

получили разреженную "One-Hot-Encoded" матрицу:

```
In [298]: r
Out[298]:
<5x6 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
        with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [299]: r.A
Out[299]:
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int64)

In [300]: vect.get_feature_names()
Out[300]: ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

теперь можно вставить ее в столбец:

```
In [301]: df['new'] = r.A.tolist()

In [302]: df
Out[302]:
       types                 new
24433      3  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
23933      1  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
23433      5  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
22933      3  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
22433      0  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Я Вам очень благодарен за Ваше время, не сочтите наглостью, Вы бы не могли объяснить как это работает:`df['new'] = df.types.astype(str).str.get_dummies().values.tolist()`    это решило мою задачу и я прислушался по поводу "все они ожидают скалярные значения в ячейках DataFrame'а"  , в следующий раз буду от этого отталкиваться.

Comment: @Oleksii, добавил небольшое пояснение в ответ...